# How to crate example daap on Astar network

Tags: astar

I would like to be a developer on Astar network.
How to crate example daap on Astar network

Answer (score 2):

You can get started with this [front-end template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template). You can set the RPC endpoint to `wss://1rpc.io/astr` in order to interact with Astar network.